# Error upgrading Ruby 1.9.2 to 1.9.3 using rvm OS X Lion

Tags: ruby, rvm

Hi I'm trying to upgrade my ruby 1.9.2 to 1.9.3 using RVM. This is what I'm doing:

```
rvm upgrade 1.9.2
Are you sure you wish to upgrade from ruby-1.9.2-p290 to     ruby-1.9.3-p0? (Y/n): y
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Installing new ruby ruby-1.9.3-p0
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #extracted to /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0 (already extracted)
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Compiling yaml in /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Installing yaml to /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/usr
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #configuring 
ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/configure.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
ERROR: Unable to install ruby ruby-1.9.3-p0.         Please install it manually to continue.
```

I'm using XCODE 4.2.1, any idea please???

This is the configure.log

```
[2012-06-20 11:31:41]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/usr 
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml-dir
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: So what does the configure.log say?

Comment: Hey @LukaD I just edited the post to show you the configure.log

Comment: This means that no compiler could be found. This link might help you. http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/01/ruby-1-9-2-install-errors-with-mac-os-x-lion-and-rvm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Update RVM `curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable && rvm reload`
2. Install [osx-gcc-installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads)
3. Read and follow instructions `rvm requirements`
4. Install ruby: rvm install 1.9.3

You could also use http://railsinsaler.org for new system installations.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to Xcode 4.3.  With a clean install I was able to get 1.9.3-p125 working.

If that doesn't work, RVM has some tips: https://rvm.io/os/osx/